# Sharing enodeURLs on a private blockchain

Tags: private-blockchain, peers, node-discovery, discovery-protocol, enode

Given a private network in which each computer knows at least one IP address where there is a geth, parity or pyEth node/peer, what is a good way of sharing [enode IDs](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/enode-url-format)? As far as I know, there is [no way to share enodes within the ethereum system](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/8713/820)?

After this is done, the peers can use `admin.addPeer(enode)` to create the Ethereum network.

Answer (score 2):

I'd consider using a distributed key-value store such as ETCD (https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/latest/getting-started-with-etcd.html). You could set up an ETCD alongside ethereum and share arbitrary data between each node.

While this works well for your specific use case, it may be worth it to consider piggybacking on the Bit Torrent DHT -- a publicly available distributed key-value store. This would be especially useful if you were to use a public block chain. There are some interesting projects out there like Peer Tweet (https://github.com/lmatteis/peer-tweet) that are doing this already.

Comment: etcd is perfect. You can @atomh33is also, quickly install redis too to get that very functionality.