# How does Expanse handle peer discovery?

Tags: parity, peers, node-discovery, expanse

I am seeing a lot of posts that suggest that peer discovery isn't possible on private networks.  Here is one:

[Automatic peer discovery in a private blockchain](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8712/automatic-peer-discovery-in-a-private-blockchain)

And another (less clear on this point):

[Peer discovery not working on private network](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2708/peer-discovery-not-working-on-private-network?noredirect=1&lq=1)

So that raises a few questions:

1) Is that actually true?

2) Is it true with Parity as well as geth?

3) If (1) is true, then does anyone know how Expanse, etc. handle peer discovery?

Thank you.

Comment: Peer discovery is possible in private networks unless you disable it. Expanse is not a private network.

Comment: Are you sure?  This post (and others) suggest otherwise about peer discovery: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8712/automatic-peer-discovery-in-a-private-blockchain

Comment: Yes, but peer discovery is still possible. However, Expanse is not a private network. Ropsten, Kovan, Rinkeby are also no private networks.

Comment: You said "Yes, but peer discovery is still possible."  Can you explain how?  That is precisely my question.  Regarding whether Expanse is "private" or not, I can see some debate since there are two known definitions of "private" for an ethereum blockchain, only one of them means "private and not public."  And since I want peer discovery it is obvious which one I am using.  But anyway that is beside the point of the question.  It sounds like you have an answer to my question.  Could you share it please?