# Why eth nodes found in ethernodes drop so much?

Tags: go-ethereum, ethernodes

I have just visited [ethernodes](https://www.ethernodes.org/history) (a website that records eth nodes)and found the nodes it found has drop to 3990 while this number is 10K about 2months ago.What happen?Is it true that Ethereum nodes are down a lot or just because  his detection method is  being blocked????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are at least a few ways of going about detecting all networks(something like recursively getting peers or via a [p2p discovery protocol based on the kademlia protocol](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7743/what-are-the-peer-discovery-mechanisms-involved-in-ethereum/7744))

I don't believe the method of detection is being blocked. It might be that the nodes are running a client that is **not being tracked by the website**. Even the total number of [geth nodes up under the client tab](https://www.ethernodes.org/) is off compared to https://etherscan.io/nodetracker.

Comment: you mean these clients dropped off  stop the active connections initiated by nodes hosted by ethernodes ?so that the number recorded has dropped ,because ethernodes thinks these are not routable anymore?if so?What has led to this shift

Comment: if so many clients refuse the active connections initiated by ethernodes,will these refuse the acitve connections form us,leading our "peerCount"down ,though I only can connetct less than ten nodes – DaJin Wei 1 hour ago   Edit   Delete

Comment: I believe its just the form of detection being inaccurate to the true number of nodes being run.